# R package for FFIEC and UBPR bank data

Tags: r, finance, banking

Is there an R package for querying data from the FFIEC and UBPR reports for bank analysis?  They have a service to access their data depository, but everything looks geared towards retrieval for web development.

*UBPR (Uniform Bank Performance Report) is public information about every Bank in the United States.  Banks file this data quarterly via what's called a "call report."

I tried to find a package and couldn't.